# How can my class instance implicitly return a number when compare with another instance?

Tags: javascript, object, compare, object-comparison

Look at this example:

```
var d1 = new Date(2016,4,1);
var d2 = new Date(2016,4,2);
if (d2 > d1){ .... }
```

As you can see in date object, when you compare two instance then they return implicitly `getTime()` method of this instances.

I want to do exact same thing with my object.

Imagine my class is something like this:

```
var myClass = function (arg1,arg2,arg3){
   ....
   ....
   ....
   this.myNumber = function (){
         return arg1 + arg2+ arg3;
   }
}
```

and I want when I compare two instances of my class then it compare the value of their `myNumber()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method for your class:

```
var myObj = function(arg1,arg2,arg3) {
   ....
   ....
   ....
   this.valueOf = function() {
     return arg1 + arg2+ arg3;
   }
}
```

See [a JS Bin demo](https://jsbin.com/zemaru/1/edit?js,console).